# Условие сравнения

Tags: php

Совсем язык заплетается.
Т.е., точнее, языки совсем спутались.
Разве в PHP такая конструкция условия не возможна?

```
if (2 < 5 < 10)
{копаем}
else
{не копаем}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, нужно явно написать `2 < 5 && 5 < 10`, потому что выполняя как компилятор (справа налево), получим `2 < ( true )`, что не является правильным.